# Numerical method to solve nonlinear autonomous ODE with state dependent matrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, nonlinear-system

I have been trying to solve numerically using MATLAB a system of ODEs, where when I introduce a state dependent function on the mass matrix (see below $T_{m1}(\theta)$), the residuals are suddenly increasing by a couple of orders of magnitude even when I use solvers such as `ode23t` which is designed to take strongly state dependent mass matrices.

To combat this I have chosen `ode45` and made it run in a loop where the last point of the solution of the previous iteration acts as the initial value for the next. Also, for each iteration loops I set $T_{m1}(\theta)$ as a constant. This levels out the residuals but takes a tremendous amount of time for only 4 degrees of freedom (4x4 matrices that take about 30mins to solve). So I was wondering weather you'd have any advice of a numerical scheme that could be more efficient.

So here is the system of equations for the system:

$[\mathbf{J}-T_{m1}(\theta)]\ddot{\theta}+\mathbf{C}\dot{\theta}-T_{m2}(\theta)\dot{\theta}^2+\mathbf{T_l}\dot{\theta}^{1.7}+\mathbf{K}\theta=T_g(\theta)$

Where $\mathbf{J}$, $\mathbf{C}$, $\mathbf{K}$, $\mathbf{T_l}$, are matrices and $T_{m1}(\theta)$, $T_{m2}(\theta)$, $T_g(\theta)$, are vector valued functions (and obviously then $\theta$ is a vector)

Thanks for your help in advance!

KMT.

P.S.

What I mean by residuals is the result of the above equation when I shift $T_g(\theta)$ to the left hand side. In an ideal world it should be equal to zero, but as the numerical scheme accumulates errors, its not.

I have also tried all of MATLAB default solvers changing the tolerances as well but the residuals were still unacceptably high.

The functions of $\theta$ are all continuous sinusoidal functions with the same period.

Comment: What is $\dot θ^{1.7}$ for a vector valued $θ$? How exactly do you compute the residuals? At the internal time steps, it should be near zero. Do you use dense output? Do you use `deval`?

Comment: Valid point: $\dot{\theta}^{1.7}$ is defined as every element of $\dot{\theta}$ raised to the $1.7$ power (as a matter of fact every vector in this equation to the power of something is defined as an element-wise operation). 

I compute the residuals after I have solved the equation and plug all the numbers back in to 

$[\mathbf{J}-T_{m1}(\theta)]\ddot{\theta}+\mathbf{C}\dot{\theta}-T_{m2}(\theta)\dot{\theta}^2+\mathbf{T_l}\dot{\theta}^{1.7}+\mathbf{K}\theta-T_g(\theta)=Residuals$. Essentially I have set up my `odefcn` to take matrices as inputs, so I use my `odefcn` anonymous function.

Comment: By "dense output" do you mean setting `tspan` as a vector which's step is smaller than the one used by the solver?

Comment: No, I mean the last output option of ode45 et al., where a method specific polynomial interpolation is returned that can be evaluated with deval at an time inside the integration interval. For some reason, this is called "dense output" instead of "continuous approximation" or similar.

Comment: It sounds like you mean the option `Refine`. I havent tried this one actually, let me see if it makes a difference.

Comment: There is no option `Refine` in Matlabs `ode45`. No, I mean this line from the documentation "`sol = ode45(___)` returns a structure that you can use with deval to evaluate the solution at any point on the interval `[t0 tf]`. You can use any of the input argument combinations in previous syntaxes." See also the [description of the `sol` structure](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#bu00_4l_sep_shared-sol)

Comment: Ok, now I understand better. So effectively this is a way to have a 'denser output' of the solution given the spacing of the vector x that I choose. Let me try this and I'l come back to you

Comment: Note that for this option, you do not choose a spacing at all, this spacing is generated by the internal steps of the solver. But from this interpolation object you can generate results with any spacing.

Comment: Indeed that worked a little better since the residuals got decreased and computation time is not as much.